# I can't kill one server using WLST and Node Manager

Tags: weblogic, weblogic9.x

I manage seven Weblogic servers for development and test.  I use WLST scripts to start and stop them.  This works perfectly for six of the servers, but one of them will not stop when I run the script to stop it.  The start script starts it but the stop script doesn't stop it.

I'm executing the same scripts for all seven servers, it's just different parameters.  WLST says it successfully shut down the server, but it's lying.  It also says this very quickly (it takes a few seconds for the ones it actually shuts down).

Has anyone else had this problem?  Do you have any clues as to what I should be looking at?

The servers are version 9.2.  My stop script looks like this:

```
from java.util import *
from javax.management import *

print 'starting the script ....'
argslength = len(sys.argv)

if argslength < 2 :
    print '==>Insufficient arguments'
    print '==>Syntax: java weblogic.WLST stop.py domain server'
    exit()
else:
    domain = sys.argv[1]
    server = sys.argv[2]
    print 'stopping server ', server, ' in domain ', domain
    nmConnect(adminId, password, host, '5556', domain)
    nmKill(server)
nmDisconnect()
exit()
```

In the real script that adminId, password and host are hard coded.

Comment: are you able to shut it down from the admin console normally or does it hang?

Comment: Yes, I can shut it down from the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

If you already resolved share your thought...
Correct me if I m wrong...
You have multiple domains on the same machine. You wish to stop all the servers by using NM.
Did you check the server which is not shutdown (lying server :)) is that enrolled by nmEnroll()?

Comment: Yes it's enrolled.  I can start the server via the NM.